# How do I fix watchman hogging my CPU cores?

Tags: macos, time-machine

Having installed watchman last night and finally getting it working this morning, now it is completely hogging my CPU, which is running at 100%

I did a `watchman watch <myfolder>` and created a trigger. Granted, the folder contains many thousands of small files (it's a Time Machine sparse bundle), but in my little head I imagined it could just watch to see if *anything* in the folder changed, without worrying too much about what those changes are, since the trigger will do the same thing (`gustil rsync`).

Couldn't really see any configuration options to limit the cores or anything of that nature. Am I asking too much?

So is it possible to do this? What are all these Python processes doing? Hopefully not watching each file! As it is, I can't have this running since it is messing with the performance of my machine.

I am running macOS Ventura, and my watched folder is on an external RAID drive.

[image: iStat]

Comment: Ask the developers if there's a configuration setting for time interval or core/thread limit. Can I ask why you're monitoring a TM backup? Manually interfering with TM backups usually ends badly. Would it not be better to monitor the source location?

Comment: It reads like the OP thinks he needs to rsync the backup to somewhere else.  Wouldn't it be better to just make the backup to the somewhere else in the first place?

Comment: @benwiggy I’m only monitoring the sparse bundle for changes so I can rsync to the cloud. I’m not changing the folder in any way.

Comment: @MarcWilson I don’t think you can configure TM to store the backup in the cloud. Unless I can mount the GCS bucket locally somehow; but it’s cold storage so I don’t fancy the fees those transactions might attract.

Comment: Although there is this: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse

Comment: What do you intend to do with it once you've used rsync to copy it?  What's the endgame here?

Comment: @MarcWilson I want to keep a copy of my backup in the cloud.

Comment: I mean, if my local RAID bursts into flames, I want a copy

Comment: To do what with?  You can't restore from it.

Comment: @MarcWilson  Er...yeah I can. I'm struggling to understand your issue with this. If I lose my local sparse bundle — if my RAID drive bursts into flames, for example — I can pull it down from GCS and restore from that. Where would you say I'm going wrong?